# To use it as jmeter slave which aws ec2 instance (t2.medium/m3.medium..) would be better for high load as not able to get results for 250 users

Tags: jmeter

Using three t2.medium ec2 instances for jmeter distributed testing (master + 2 slaves). When tested with this setup able to successfully get results for 200 users for a website homepage running in jmeter non GUI mode from master however when tried for 250 users results are not generated (hanged/frozen at summary results) and not able to get results after waiting for some time.
How will we know if the given system/instance configuration is not enough or need to increase to m3.medium or any other higher range instances for slaves to generate users. Should i capture any logs/tcpdumps or something else to analyse what instance would be good enough to test 500 users?
Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all make sure you have [optimatl JMeter configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)
2. Start with 1 virtual user on 1 virtual machine and gradually increase the load at the same time monitoring virtual machine resources consumption via [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). When you observe one of the following metrics growing above 90% of maximum:

   - CPU consumption
   - free RAM
   - Disk or Network IO maximum capacity
   - system start swapping

   stop the test and check what was the number of active users at this time (you can use i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener plugin. This is how may users you can simulate using one virtual machine.
3. Given both slaves have the same specifications and setup you should be able to simulate the same amount on the each slave, i.e.

   - if you have 200 users defined in Thread Group and one slave - total load will be 200 users
   - if you have 200 users defined in Thread Group and two slaves - total load will be 400 users
   - etc.
4. Remember that the maximum amount of users may vary depending on what your test is doing so if you are able to kick off 500 users for one application it doesn't necessarily mean that this is the maximum, it can be higher or less